# How do I fix the "found Rust tuple type in foreign module; consider using a struct instead" warning

Tags: c, rust

```
use std::ptr;

#[repr(C)]
struct timeval {
    tv_sec: i64,
    tv_usec: i64
}

extern {
    fn gettimeofday(tv: &mut timeval, tzp: *const ()) -> i32;
}

fn time1000() -> i64 {
    let mut tv = timeval { tv_sec: 0, tv_usec: 0 };
    unsafe {
        gettimeofday(&mut tv, ptr::null());
    }
    tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000
}
```

The code above works, but I get this warning:

```
test.rs:10:44: 10:53 warning: found Rust tuple type
    in foreign module; consider using a struct instead`, #
[warn(improper_ctypes)] on by default
test.rs:10     fn gettimeofday(tv: &mut timeval, tzp: *const ()) -> i32;
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~
```

The message is verbose, but I am unable to understand what is wrong with this `*const()` thing and how to satisfy the compiler here.

Comment: I think it's saying () isn't a C type, so it doesn't make sense to pass a pointer to one to C. You should declare `struct tz` too. Also, I'm not sure it's correct to pass a reference, rather than a raw pointer.

Answer (score 3):

`()` is a tuple (the empty tuple).  The memory layout of tuples is not guaranteed to be compatible with C, so tuples shouldn't be used in a foreign function interface. Hence the warning.

Instead of a tuple you should use a struct, [as the representation of structs is guaranteed to be compatible with C](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#interoperability-with-foreign-code).

So to get rid of the warning you could define some dummy struct and use it as the type for the tzp null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick an dirty solution is to define a empty `tz` enum and declare `tzp:*const tz`. As you use `ptr::null()` for `tzp`, that is fine.

```
enum tz {}

extern "C" {
    fn gettimeofday(tv: &mut timeval, tzp: *const tz) -> i32;
}
```

But you should be using `libc` crate instead of creating your own binding. The `libc` crate works on many platforms, and your bind does not. For example, you are assuming that `time_t` (type of `tv_sec`) is `i64`, but [it can be](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/search?q=time_t&type=Code) `i32` in some platforms.

```
extern crate libc;

use std::ptr;
use libc::{timeval, gettimeofday};

fn time1000() -> i64 {
    let mut tv = timeval { tv_sec: 0, tv_usec: 0 };
    unsafe {
        gettimeofday(&mut tv, ptr::null_mut());
    }
    (tv.tv_sec as i64) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec as i64) / 1000
}
```